# Alternative of @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

What is the alternative of rollback transaction in spring except @Transactional annotation.
I have used this annotation but i want the way by which i can rollback transaction in catch block. Is there any way?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: why do you need to rollback in a catch block?

Comment: i have a situation like where i need to rollback in catch block and need to do some process in catch block.

Comment: You need to rollback and then process or process and then rollback?

Comment: i need to rollback and then process, and need to continue controller's excecution flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a draft:**

```
public class SomeService implements SomeInterface {

   private SomeDao thisDaoWrapsJdbcTemplate;
   private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

   public void setTransactionManager( PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager ) {
      this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
   }

   public void doBusiness( Business: business ) {

      TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
      TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction( def );

      try {

         // do business here
         Money money = Money.LOTS_OF
         ...
         // wire the money in..
         thisDaoWrapsJdbcTemplate.depositLotsOfMoney( money )

         transactionManager.commit( status );

      } catch ( DataAccessException dae ) {

         transactionManager.rollback( status );
         throw dae;
      }
      return;
   }
```

Comment: i have used TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly() in catch block, which rollbacks transaction done in try block. But, what if i do any transaction after this line in catch block? will be be rolled back too?

Comment: In above draft will be rollbacked only the transactionstatus (current)... if you setRollbackOnly, by javadoc "This instructs the transaction manager that the only possible outcome of the transaction may be a rollback"